# TerminateWorkflow Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

i am working on an ASP .net workflow application and i have a TerminateWorkflow control in the workflow Visual designer. But when i run the Asp .net application the browser keep "Waiting" when it reaches the TerminateWorkflow control. Do you have any ideas? Thx for your time.

Comment: How are you running your workflow? With the WorkflowApplication? And show us some code.

Comment: Yes i m running it with WorkflowApplication. I don't have any code for the Termination of the workflow. I designed it with the Visual designer of the VS2010. Do i have to add any code for the Termination? or it works automatically and terminate the workflow?.

Comment: How about the code that starts the workflow.

Comment: var app = new WorkflowApplication(new Activity1(), input); app.Run();

Comment: If i remove the TerminateWorfklow control it works fine!

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I can't. When the page is loaded, I started a WorkflowApplication with a simple Activity (with one TerminateWorkflow), but it could be loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The TerminateWorkflow activity throws an exception -- so if it's unhandled I'm not sure what kind of results you're going to see but you may see your application hang.  Is your Run command wrapped in a Try/Catch?